# Joining 2 tables

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

This is my query

```
SELECT Testcases.Testcase, Tests.Result
FROM Testcases LEFT JOIN Tests ON Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID
WHERE Tests.Release="1.1.111";
```

However, what I want is to get ALL rows in Testcases, no matter if `Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID`. For each row in Tests, there is a single row in Testcases for the given release number.

Samples:

```
Testcases table
---------------
ID Testcase
1  TC-1
2  TC-5
3  TC-8

Tests table
-----------
ID TestCaseID Result Release
1  1          OK     1.1.111
2  3          FAIL   1.1.111
```

What I want to get is

```
Testcase Result
TC-1     OK
TC-5     <empty>
TC-8     FAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use outer join:

```
SELECT tc.Testcase, t.Result
FROM Testcases as tc, 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tests as t 
ON Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID
WHERE Tests.Release="1.1.111";
```

Comment: Access doesn't like this `as` syntax, however even after replacing haven't got ALL records from Testcase table. I've updated original post to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

If Tests.TestcaseID does not equal Testcases.ID then it isn't a join. Are you trying to get the Cartesian product?

If you just want all rows in Testcases then just do SELECT * from TESTCASES.

It isn't clear what you want - why don't you give a 3-row table example?

Answer (score -1):

finally this worked for me, try it.

```
SELECT Testcases.Testcase, Tests.Result
FROM Testcases LEFT OUTER JOIN Tests ON Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID 
WHERE Tests.Release="1.1.111"
```

Comment: Edited, This should result as you want, did you tested it ?

Comment: yes, it give me rows TC-1, TC-1, TC-1, TC-2, TC-2, TC-2, ... instead it should give TC-1, TC-2, TC-3.. please see my original post

Comment: Its because you have multiple Tests for each TestCase in your tables, then if you want to remove this repetitive you should use distinct. see my edited answer.

Comment: I have only 1 Test per each test case for the given release. This doesn't work because of `FindLastTestResult`. Even if I remove it, I am still not getting ALL test cases.

Comment: Again, there is no need to get last test result, because for given release the test result is unique to testcase.

Comment: ok, I am going to edit to new query. I tested and it worked for me

Comment: no it doesn't work... meanwhile the doc says that it SHOULD return the full rows from the left table, so there is no need for magic like outer... I've simplified question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693955/left-join-in-not-returning-full-rows-from-left-table-in-ms-access/5694027#5694027