# LEFT JOIN in not returning full rows from left table in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
Testcases table
---------------
ID Testcase
1  TC-1
2  TC-5
3  TC-8

Tests table
-----------
ID TestCaseID Result Release
1  1          OK     1.1.111
2  3          FAIL   1.1.111
```

What I want to get is

```
Testcase Result
TC-1     OK
TC-5     <empty>
TC-8     FAIL
```

What I get is

```
Testcase Result
TC-1     OK
TC-8     FAIL
```

Query:

```
SELECT Testcases.Testcase, Tests.Result
FROM Testcases LEFT JOIN Tests ON Testcases.ID=Tests.TestCaseID
WHERE Tests.Release="1.1.111";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two (subtly) different ways to do that:

```
SELECT Testcases.Testcase
     , Tests.Result
FROM Testcases
  LEFT JOIN Tests
    ON (  ( Testcases.ID = Tests.TestCaseID )
      AND ( Tests.Release = "1.1.111" )
       )
```

and:

```
SELECT Testcases.Testcase
     , Tests.Result
FROM Testcases
  LEFT JOIN Tests
    ON Testcases.ID = Tests.TestCaseID
WHERE Tests.Release = "1.1.111"
   OR Tests.TestCaseID IS NULL
```

Insert one more row into table `Testcases`, with `ID=4, Testcase=20`

and a row into table `Tests`, with `TestCaseID=4 Result="Whatever" Release="2.2.37"` to see the difference between the 2 options.

In short, first query will show all Testscases, with results shown only for tests having `Release="1.1.111"`, the rest testcases will show Results as empty (NULL).

The second will show only Testscases having tests with `Release="1.1.111"`. And also all Testcase without any test.

**Note:** The 1st query cannot be shown in Access' "Design" mode. You can save it in SQL mode but it appears that if you close and reopen it, Access erases some parentheses for unknown reasons. You can still run it though.

It (1st query) can also be written as:

```
SELECT Testcases.Testcase
     , g.Result
FROM Testcases
 LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT * 
     FROM Tests
     WHERE ( Tests.Release = "1.1.111" )
   )
   AS g
 ON ( Testcases.ID = g.TestCaseID )
```

or

```
SELECT Testcases.TestCase
     , Tests.Result
FROM Testcases
  INNER JOIN Tests
    ON ( Testcases.ID = Tests.TestCaseID )
WHERE ( Tests.Release = "1.1.111" ) 

UNION ALL 

SELECT Testcases.TestCase, NULL
FROM Testcases 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM Tests
    WHERE ( Testcases.ID = Tests.TestCaseID )
      AND ( Tests.Release = "1.1.111" )
  )
```

or even better (because it can be shown in Design mode):

```
SELECT Testcases.Testcase
     , IIf((Tests.Release="1.1.111"), Tests.Result, Null)
       AS Result
FROM Testcases
  LEFT JOIN Tests
    ON Testcases.ID = Tests.TestCaseID
GROUP BY Testcases.Testcase
       , IIf((Tests.Release="1.1.111"), Tests.Result, Null)
```

Comment: the first gives me "Join expression not supported on `Tests.Release=..` part. The second works, but curious to know the difference and make sure this covers what I want.

Comment: with your pointed case and second way, I am still not getting the full set of rows from testcases.

Comment: @Michael: Edited the 1st query, it needed a pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Put the filter into your join criteria, so that it's applied as part of the join, rather than filtered afterwards.  e.g.:

```
SELECT Testcases.Testcase, Tests.Result
FROM (Testcases LEFT JOIN Tests ON ((Testcases.ID=Tests.TestCaseID)
 AND (Tests.Release="1.1.111")))
```

Comment: When you put a condition in the where clause, it'll make an inner join on your left joined table, so as @steve says, you'll need to move the condition

Comment: MS Access is not accepting this... also tried with braces, same result :(

Comment: How to "move" condition guys?

Comment: I've modified my answer (with brackets) - can you try again?

Comment: This pickiness about braces and brackets is a reason to consider using the Access GUI to design complex queries.

Comment: @le dorfier: You are right but some queries (like this one) cannot be shown in Access GUI :). Only in Access SQL mode.

Comment: You can create a querydef for the subquery, and then another querydef that uses the first as the source.